# react-native-webview error at first launch

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webview

I have a custom URL scheme on my webview source (atrium://)
I'm handling the URL in "onNavigationStateChange" and "onShouldStartLoadWithRequest"
everything works fine except when I start the app.
if I enter the app and go to the webview, it gives me the Error "UNKNOW_URL_SCHEME URL :atrium://..." but if I go back and enter into the webview again it works!
I dont know what causes this error at the first time app loads .
this is the code :

```
const handleWebViewNavigationStateChange = newNavState => {
     const { url } = newNavState;
     console.log("URL : ", url)
     if (url.startsWith('atrium://')) {
       return false
     }
  }




   <WebView
     setSupportMultipleWindows={false}
     ref={webView}
     originWhitelist={['http://*', 'https://*', 'atrium://*']}
     source={{ uri: route.params.url }}
     style={{ flex: 1 }}
     javaScriptEnabled={true}
     onNavigationStateChange={handleWebViewNavigationStateChange}
     onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={handleWebViewNavigationStateChange}     
   />
```

and route.params.url is something like this :
"https://int-widgets.moneydesktop.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%3D"

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <WebView
        {...this.props}
        bounces={false}
        originWhitelist={["https://*", "http://*", "file://*", "sms://*", 'atrium://*']}
        allowFileAccess={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        geolocationEnabled={true}
        saveFormDataDisabled={true}
        allowFileAccessFromFileURLS={true}
        allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
      />
```

or modify your function like this:

```
function onShouldStartLoadWithRequest(request){
  if (!request || !request.url) {
    return true;
  }

  // list of schemas we will allow the webview
  // to open natively
  if(request.url.startsWith("tel:") ||
    request.url.startsWith("mailto:") ||
    request.url.startsWith("maps:") ||
    request.url.startsWith("geo:") ||
    request.url.startsWith("sms:")
    ){
    Linking.openURL(request.url).catch(er => {
      console.log('Failed to open Link:', er.message);
    });
    return false;
  }

  // let everything else to the webview
  return true;
}
```